# Send image to API with base64 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, base64

I want to take a picture from the user and give it to the API with base64.
This is just a datasource for user registration in clean architecture.
I tried this way:

```
class RegisterRemoteDataSourceImpl extends RegisterRemoteDataSource {
  final http.Client client;
  final String username, email, password, confirmPassword;
  final String fullname, biography;
  final File? profilePicture;
  final Location? location;

  RegisterRemoteDataSourceImpl({
    required this.client,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.confirmPassword,
    required this.fullname,
    required this.biography,
    this.location,
    this.profilePicture,
  });

  @override
  // register user
  Future<bool> register() async {
    // create register uri from register url
    final uri = Uri.parse(kApiRegister);

    final boundary = Random.secure().nextInt(1000);

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary'
    };

    List<int> imageBytes = profilePicture!.readAsBytesSync();
    String base64Image = base64Encode(imageBytes);
    String pre = "data:image/jpg;base64,";

    // body
    final body = jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
      "username": username,
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
      "confirm_password": confirmPassword,
      "fullname": fullname,
      "biography": biography,
      "location": const Location(latitude: 12, longitude: 12).toJson(),
      "profile_picture": "$pre$base64Image",
    });

    final response = await http.post(uri, body: body, headers: headers);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    } else {
      throw (response.body);
    }
  }
}
```

and I tested it manually, and it
throws an exception:

> "{"error":"Username is required."}"

but I filled this field.

After that I tried to do that with http.

```
class RegisterRemoteDataSourceImpl extends RegisterRemoteDataSource {
  final http.Client client;
  final String username, email, password, confirmPassword;
  final String fullname, biography;
  final File? profilePicture;
  final Location? location;

  RegisterRemoteDataSourceImpl({
    required this.client,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.password,
    required this.confirmPassword,
    required this.fullname,
    required this.biography,
    this.location,
    this.profilePicture,
  });

  @override
  Future<bool> register() async {
    // create register uri from register url
    final uri = Uri.parse(kApiRegister);

    Map<String, String> headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'};

    // body
    final body = <String, String>{
      "username": username,
      "email": email,
      "password": password,
      "confirm_password": confirmPassword,
      "fullname": fullname,
      "biography": biography,
      // It has no special effect, it can be empty
      // "location": const Location(latitude: 12, longitude: 12).toJson(),
    };

    final request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri)
      ..headers.addAll(headers)
      ..fields.addAll(body)
      ..files.add(
        await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
          "profile_picture",
          profilePicture!.path,
        ),
      );

    final response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    } else {
      throw (response.reasonPhrase.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

This was done successfully,
but when I use `http.MultipartFile.fromBytes()` its not working:

```
final request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri)
      ..headers.addAll(headers)
      ..fields.addAll(body)
      ..files.add(
        http.MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          "profile_picture",
          profilePicture!.readAsBytesSync(),
          // await profilePicture!.readAsBytes()
        ),
      );
```

and when use `http.MultipartFile.fromPath`, it works.

Comment: Isn't it a case issue ? Does it expect "Username" instead of "username" ?

Comment: no, its not, in body its must be "username"

Comment: Seems it a server side error or incorrect parameter spelling

Comment: I don't think so because when I use it with `http.MultipartFile` there is no problem, so the problem must be from my side